# email attachment issue in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, email, attachment

Hi I am trying to send a picture attachment to some email via ASP.NET. The program works without any problem, but I cannot visualize the attached picture in some email programs, such as iPhone's email program for Yahoo email. I suspect I am not attaching correctly the picture. 
It works ok on my desktop pc

When the email is loaded I cannot see the picture.

```
   Dim mail As New MailMessage()
    mail.From = New MailAddress("xxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxx")
    mail.To.Add(DirectCast(RegisterUser.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("Email"), TextBox).Text)
    mail.Subject = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    mail.Body = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

    Dim htmlBody As String = "<html><body><DIV style=""background-color:#5B37AE"">"
    htmlBody += "<img height=""70px"" width=""150px"" src=cid:HDIImage /></DIV></body></html>"

    Dim htmlView As System.Net.Mail.AlternateView = System.Net.Mail.AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(htmlBody, Nothing, "text/html")
    Dim imageResource As New System.Net.Mail.LinkedResource(Server.MapPath("~/Images/Site/background_main2.png"))
    imageResource.ContentId = "HDIImage"
    htmlView.LinkedResources.Add(imageResource)


    mail.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView)

    Dim j As New SmtpClient
    j.Host = "hostingxxxxx"
    j.EnableSsl = False
    j.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("usernam", "passw")

    j.Send(mail)
```

Thanks

Comment: email clients have setting to enable and disable html in msgs, first step is to check for that setting.

Comment: Rewrite your question's title in more concrete phrases avoiding word "issue", please.

Answer (score 1):

It was not necessary to attach via linkedresoruce, adding `src="http://wwww.mysite.com/myimage.jpg"` works ok in every (modern) browser